# In Isaiah 44:7 who are the "ancient people"?

Tags: isaiah, referent-identification

In Isaiah 44:7 the LORD says:

> Let him declare and lay out before me what has happened since I established my **ancient people** (NIV)

Who are the ancient people?

Comment: In context, this seems to be saying that anyone who claims to be "like God" should know both history and the future. Probably ancient refers to since the beginning of the human race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will quote the entire Scripture as it appears in the New King James version:

> Isaiah 44:7  And who, as I, shall call, and shall declare it, and set it in order for me, since I appointed the ancient people? and the things that are coming, and shall come, let them shew unto them.

That verse alone leaves much unknown;

1. Who is he talking with?
2. Whom is he talking about prior to referring to the Ancient people?
3. What incident is he referring to?
4. How are they to shew unto them.

If we are to answer these questions we must take into account some other Scriptures, first of all we must take the entire chapter of Isaiah 44 and understand that so in effort to understand that let's look at Bridgeway's Bible commentary;

> > Israel’s God and man-made gods (44:1-28)
> >     Not only is God willing to forgive his people, but he wants to pour out the power of his Spirit upon them so that new spiritual life will spring up within them. This will enable them to evangelize the Gentiles, who will then join the descendants of Jacob in worshipping the God of Israel (44:1-5). Israel’s redeemer is the only God. He knows the end from the beginning and his people can depend on him always (6-8).
> >     In contrast to the one true and living God are the many lifeless gods that workmen make. But how can a man make a god? What he makes must be inferior to himself, not greater. By making idols a person lowers his own status and brings shame upon himself (9-11).
> >     When a craftsman makes an idol of metal, he gets hot and tired from his work, and the idol can do nothing to help him (12). When a craftsman makes an idol of wood, he has to use a tree that the living God has made to grow. After the man has chopped the tree down, he uses part of it to make a fire to cook his meals, and uses another part of it to make an idol that he then worships (13-17). To worship man-made things is clearly absurd, but those who worship them cannot see this, because they are spiritually blind (18-20).
> >     The prophet then returns to consider the one true God and what he has done for his people. He has chosen them to belong to him, forgiven them their sins and saved them from their enemies (21-23). He is their redeemer as well as their creator, and he is now about to prove wrong those who forecast the destruction of Israel (24-25). As the prophet has already announced, God is going to act on behalf of his people. At his direction Cyrus will conquer Babylon and permit the Jews to return and rebuild Jerusalem (26-28).

After analyzing the full Chapter we realize that what God is really talking about is his master plan in Creation, and the Ancient ones must therefore refer to the ascendency beginning with Adam and Eve whom God used to perpetuate his plan.

He is telling the Nation of Israel that he has not and will not forsake them, and for proof all they need do is look at how he has cared for them throughout History. Not withstanding they must also look at his warnings and history of punishment. That is still true of the Nation of Israel today.

> 2nd Chronicles 7:14 KJV  If my people, which are called by my name, shall humble themselves, and pray, and seek my face, and turn from their wicked ways; then will I hear from heaven, and will forgive their sin, and will heal their land.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ancients are people like Melchizedic.  He is also an ancient and I think they are still living and also have divine powers.  Mechizedic is not dead, no one knows where he is; perhaps still living with the other ancients.  I say this because I had an encounter with a male and a female who looked like ancients.  I was also told that a person, even after thousands of years was still breading.  The appeared to be eastern.
BELIEVE IT OR NOT.

Answer (score 0):

The true descendants of Israel, & they are not those Ashkenazi claiming to be Jews today. Scripture has plainly informed all who read & understand the true Jews would go into slavery & be scattered into every nation & will forget who they are but in the land of their captivity they shall remember themselves. I would say who they are but there will be arguments & debates which I will not engage in, no need to since prophecies concerning them is unfolding & will continue unfold & soon all will soon have the undeniable proof who they are & will just have to accept it- though higher power have spent billions to hide their true identity & continue to try to suppress it, but all in vain cause prophecies cannot be broken.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Site evidence to support your Antisemitic remarks that Jews are not Jews.